# Passing a token/value into an application express custom authentication scheme

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am trying to pass an encrypted token from an external application into Application Express. I want to read and work with this token in a custom authentication scheme as a way to authenticate the user into the application.

What is the best way to do this? At first, I was trying to just append the token onto the URL, eg:

```
/pls/apex/f?p=999:1&Token=XXXXXXXX
```

But then Apex returns a 404.

So then, I was trying to use the Application Express session values to send in the token, creating a URL like this:

```
f?p=999:1:::::TOKEN:XXXXXXXX
```

And then my sentry function I would do something like:

```
v_token := V('TOKEN')
```

To get it. However, this isn't working either, and I think's because the session isn't established yet when the sentry function executes? And is it even possible to do it this way? (Since there would be no item with this name, and no page yet to create it on...)

Is there a better approach to doing what I'm trying to do? If I had this added as a HTTP Header upstream, can I read that somehow in the sentry function? Maybe with owa_util.get_cgi_env? Does that work to read HTTP Headers from the request?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into something like this - I figured out a workaround.

Just put the token in the "value" session variables section of the URL, like so

```
f?p=999:1::::::XXXXXXXX
```

Then in the "sentry function" I can get the entire query string like this:

```
v_query_str := owa_util.get_cgi_env('QUERY_STRING');
```

And then I can split `v_query_str` by `:` and get the 8th token, which is what I need.

I found some examples using  `apex_util.string_to_table` to split the string, which works nicely.